# jq, when to use the dot and when not

Tags: syntax, jq, abbreviation

Consider [the following `json` string](https://gist.github.com/suntong/5d7d546c3ab075fb17c7693b4d3cc855):

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "repositoryCount": 24,
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
            "url": "https://github.com/Urigo/leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
            "description": "Open bank data for Leumi bank and Leumi card credit card",
            . . . 
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "puppeteer-demo",
            "url": "https://github.com/xJkit/puppeteer-demo",
            "description": "A demo for website scrapping by my puppet :>",
            . . .
```

If to use `jq` to select the `data`, then it needs a dot (`.`) before it. I.e.:

```
jq 'data' 
jq: error: data/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
data
jq: 1 compile error
```

However `jq '.data'` works fine, and the selected data becomes:

```
{
  "search": {
    "repositoryCount": 24,
    "edges": [
      {
      ...
```

If to use `jq` to select the `search`, *after the pipe*, then it *does not* need a dot (`.`) before it. I.e.:

```
$ jq '.data | {.search} ' 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.data | {.search}          
jq: 1 compile error
```

However `jq '.data.search'` works fine.

Moreover, a more complicated example,

```
jq '.data.search.edges[] | {node} '
```

works fine, but

```
jq '.data.search.edges[] | {node.name} '
```

gives:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.data.search.edges[] | {node.name}                             
jq: 1 compile error
```

So, all in all, I'm rather confused when to use the dot (`.`) and when not to, when using `jq`. Please help. Thx.

Comment: This Q/A helped me find a [better Github search approach](https://medium.com/@suntong001/query-github-graphql-9a4547d33bad), FYI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps things will be clearer if you begin by thinking of the full data pipeline involved, and recognize when an expression is just an abbreviated form.

In constructing an unabbreviated pipeline, the basic principles regarding "dots" are quite simple:

- `.` refers to the input
- `.foo` is for accessing the value of the key "foo"
- `.[]` is for expanding an array or object

There are many allowed abbreviations.  The two that seem to have confused you the most are:

- `.foo.bar` for `.foo | .bar`
- `{foo}` for `{"foo": .foo}`

Another important abbreviation is:

- `E[]` for `E | .[]` where E is a suitably compact expression

With these principles and examples in mind, you should be able to master the details as explained in the jq documentation.

Comment: That's wonderful peak, thanks. I tried to use the above principle to make  `'.data.search.edges[] | {node.name} '` working for the given example in OP, but I'm still failing. How to make it works, and why the new way is working, not `'.data.search.edges[] | {node.name} '`? Thx.

Comment: You cannot get to `{node.name}` by any route because JSON objects have keys and values.  The most general single-key JSON object constructor in jq takes the form: `{(KEY): VALUE}`, where KEY and VALUE are appropriate jq expressions.

Comment: That's strange, because I saw in https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/#result4 that `'.[] | {message: .commit.message, name: .commit.committer.name}'` is working. I.e., I don't see it any different than my using `{node.name}`. I've also tried `'.data.search.edges[1] | {name: node.name} '`, which seems to be equivalent with `{message: .commit.message}` but that is not working either: `jq: error: node/0 is not defined`.

Comment: Ops, `{name: .node.name}` works, let me try the rest of things that I need to try then accept your answer. Mean while, IMO, you may reconsider the `You cannot get to {node.name} by any route` statement, and add/explain *that* case in the answer. Thx.